# Get part of a string from the output of Get-Item in Powershell

Tags: powershell

My powershell command below

```
$BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE= (Get-Item Env:\BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)
```

returns output in this format

```
2018-10-26T01:08:44.7409834Z BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE     Merge 569594f057e2c4bd0320159855e81e14216ca66f into 41107d0f0db5ef2986831db2182280e0c...
```

I am trying to parse the string *569594f057e2c4bd0320159855e81e14216ca66f* from the output above.

I tried converting the output to a string, splitting it on whitespace, and accessing the second element of the array as follows. However, I get empty string. How can I access the required string?

```
echo $BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE
$out = $BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE | Out-String
$out1 = $out.split()
echo $out1[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concise equivalent of command `Get-Item Env:\BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE` - i.e., retrieving the value of environment variable `BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE` - is the expression `$env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE`.

Using the unary form of Powershell's `-split` operator, which splits the input by any nonempty run of whitespace (while stripping leading and trailing whitespace), you can get the desired output as follows:

```
PS> (-split $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)[3]
569594f057e2c4bd0320159855e81e14216ca66f
```

Index `3` extracts the *4th* token resulting from the tokenization via `-split`.

---

If you want to use string interpolation with the result:

```
$prefix = 'before<'; $postfix = '>after'
$val = (-split $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)[3]

# Output a synthesized string that applies a pre- and postfix, using
# {...} to enclose variable names to avoid ambiguity.
"${prefix}${val}${postfix}"
```

The above yields:

```
before<569594f057e2c4bd0320159855e81e14216ca66f>after
```